# How to use ofstream as a part of struct - arg of function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, reference, stream

I am trying to use `ofstream`, opened in function `getlog()` in function `WriteLine()`. I have a structure named `LOG`:

```
struct LOG {
    wchar_t logfile[PARM_MAX_SIZE];
    std::ofstream* stream;
};
```

which is an argument of function `WriteLine()`. When I am trying to use this stream, there is an error of reading.

I am trying to use a reference on a `LOG` variable. I tried to convert `ofstream* stream` to `ofstream&` but I don't know how to do it properly, because initialization of a `LOG` is:

```
static const LOG INITLOG {L"", NULL};
```

and I don't know how to change it to use a reference on a stream.

Functions:

```
LOG getlog(wchar_t logfile[]) {
    ofstream logf(logfile, ios::app);
    if (!logf.is_open()) {
        throw ERROR_THROW(112)
    }
    LOG log{};
    wcscpy_s(log.logfile, logfile);
    log.stream = &logf;
    return log;
}

void WriteLine(LOG log, char* c, ...) {
    char str[80]{};
    char** p = &c;
    while (*p[0]) {
        strcat_s(str, *p);
        p++;
    }
    str[strlen(str)] = '\0';
    ofstream* logf = log.stream;
    *logf << "str";
}
```

main function

```
int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Log::LOG log = Log::INITLOG;
    try {
        Parm::PARM parms = Parm::getparm(argc, argv);
        log = Log::getlog(parms.log);
        Log::WriteLine(log, (char*)"Тест:", (char*)" без ошибок \n", "");
        /*Log::WriteLine(log, (wchar_t*)L"Тест:", (wchar_t*)L" без ошибок \n", L"");
        Log::WriteLog(log);*/
    }
    catch (Error::ERROR e) {
        cout << "Ошибка " << e.id << ": " << e.message << ", строка " << e.inext.line << ", позиция " << e.inext.col << endl << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: References *must* be initialized immediately, and once set it's not possible to rebind a reference. If you want to change "reference" or if you want a reference to "nothing" (similar to a null pointer) then you can't use actual references, you must use pointers.

Comment: On a different note, `NULL` is a C-compatibility macro. In C++ please use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Also, do NOT use va_args (`void WriteLine(LOG log, char* c, ...)` ) in "C++" it is a "C" relic and very likely to end up in buggy code. C++ has variadic template functions for this. An everywhere you use char*'s or something similar consider using std::string_view

Comment: Your `getlog()` function returns a struct (of type `LOG`) containing a pointer to `logf`, which is defined locally to the function, so has automatic storage duration.   So `logf` will be destructed as the function returns, and `log.stream` in `_tmain()` will be a dangling reference.   `WriteLine()` then dereferences that pointer, giving undefined behaviour.   You need to ensure the stream continues to exist for as long as it is used - there are various options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getlog()` function is creating a new stream and returning it, but is doing so by returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope when the function exits.  To avoid that, you will need to create the stream dynamically instead, eg:

```
struct LOG {
    std::wstring logfile;
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> stream;
};

LOG getlog(const wchar_t* logfile) {
    LOG log;
    log.logfile = logfile;
    log.stream = std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(logfile, std::ios::app);
    if (!log.stream->is_open()) {
        throw ERROR_THROW(112)
    }
    return log;
}

template<typename... Args>
void WriteLine(LOG& log, Args&&... args) {
    (*(log.stream) << ... << args) << '\n';
}

int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    try {
        Parm::PARM parms = Parm::getparm(argc, argv);
        Log::LOG log = Log::getlog(parms.log);
        Log::WriteLine(log, "Тест:", " без ошибок ");
        /*Log::WriteLine(log, L"Тест:", L" без ошибок ");
        Log::WriteLog(log);*/
    }
    catch (Error::ERROR e) {
        cout << "Ошибка " << e.id << ": " << e.message << ", строка " << e.inext.line << ", позиция " << e.inext.col << endl << endl;
    }

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```